# Ibatis Ref Curosr issue with Oracle

Tags: java, oracle, oracle10g, ibatis

I'm using Java and Ibatis to call a stored procedure on on oracle database. I seem to be having an issue setting up with parameters.

The store procedure looks like the following:

```
PROCEDURE Get_Semployees_By_Clt_ID
    (
        client_id IN HRIS.SEMPLOYEES.SEE_CLT_ID%TYPE,    
        ref_cursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
    );
```

My Ibatis SqlMap:

```
<sqlMap namespace="Foo">


<resultMap id="employee-map" class="MyFoo">  
   <result property="foo1" column="foo1"/>  
   <result property="foo2" column="foo2"/>  
</resultMap>   

<parameterMap id="clientEmployeesParms" class="java.util.Map" >
    <parameter property="in1" jdbcType="INTEGER" javaType="java.lang.Integer" mode="IN"/>
    <parameter property="output1" jdbcType="ORACLECURSOR" javaType="java.sql.ResultSet"    mode="OUT" />
</parameterMap>

    <procedure id="clientEmployees" parameterMap="clientEmployeesParms" resultMap="employee-map">
    { call Package.Get_Clt_ID(?,?) }
    </procedure>

</sqlMap>
```

My Java:

```
resource = "SqlMapConfig.xml";
reader = Resources.getResourceAsReader (resource);
sqlMap = SqlMapClientBuilder.buildSqlMapClient(reader);
Map map = new HashMap();
map.put("in1", new Integer(23));
list = sqlMap.queryForList("Foo.clientEmployees", map);
```

Error:

```
--- The error occurred while applying a parameter map.  
--- Check the Employee.clientEmployeesParms.  
--- Check the output parameters (retrieval of output parameters failed).  
--- Cause: java.lang.NullPointerException
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.mapping.statement.GeneralStatement.executeQueryWithCallback(GeneralStatement.java:188)
 at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.mapping.statement.GeneralStatement.executeQueryForList(GeneralStatement.java:123)
 at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapExecutorDelegate.queryForList(SqlMapExecutorDelegate.java:610)
 at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapExecutorDelegate.queryForList(SqlMapExecutorDelegate.java:584)
 at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapSessionImpl.queryForList(SqlMapSessionImpl.java:101)
 at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapClientImpl.queryForList(SqlMapClientImpl.java:78)
 at com.apache.struts.employee.model.IbatisStoredProcedure.main(IbatisStoredProcedure.java:30)
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Peter. Are you going through bootcamp? (I work where you work, possibly in the same building. I'll shoot you an email tomorrow.)

I think the problem is because the resultMap needs to have the property names be the same as what is being returned by the procedure. In this case, whatever is being selected into the cursor.

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same problem. It is produced when you have iBatis prior to 2.1.5 and log4j in the classpath.

You can find more information here:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IBATIS-152

Update to iBatis 2.1.5 or remove log4j from classpath.

Answer (score 0):

I work with iBatis.NET and Oracle and the way I was able to get the refcursor back from a stored procedure is as follows (Note that the output parameter is First in the list, and the property/column match the sproc:

```
<parameterMap id="GetServiceTypes-param">
            <parameter property="P_CURSOR" direction="Output" column="P_CURSOR" dbType="RefCursor"/>
            <parameter property="P_TYPSERVICETYPE" direction="Input" />
</parameterMap>
```

..

```
  PROCEDURE GETSERVICETYPES(P_CURSOR OUT CURDATA, 
                            P_TYPSERVICETYPE CLM_SERVICE_TYPES_TBL.SERVICETYPE%TYPE := NULL);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I was actually able to solve this issue by using a more recent Ibatis release.